# My page is not horizontally contained. What CSS is causing this?

Tags: css

This is the webpage I am designing using Bootstrap. For the life of me, I can't figure out what is causing that small blank space to the right of the screen, which makes the website be scroll-able horizontally. Would anyone take a look please?

Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: This blank space to the right of the screen is caused by the image in the "Email Marketing: Success" section. You can fix by adding style to ` img` and their parent `div`

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [MCVE] and put it in **the question itself** instead. Stackoverflow does support [inline live demos](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `* { outline: 1px solid black }` to see which element is overflowing your site. This should help you to identify it.

Answer (score 1):

This image is causing your problem

[image]

You can set that `img` with `width: 100%` that will make your UI fit again. (It also depends what you're expecting from your designs)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Above both methods are usable to get answer as well as to identify the problem by using border. and I would suggest you to always insert width and height of the image and also insert some text inside `alt:"";` so if your image will not load you may see this text so you can find the problem for the same.
for this you can add `width: 100% and height: auto;`

Thanks,
Happy Coding...